# How to use the current value in a reader as a parameter in an sql query?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working on a project where I have to take a group of ID's and check to see if they meet certain credentials. I've decided to do this using a while loop with a reader. I basically need to know if I can grab the ID that is in the reader and use that as a parameter to query another table in my DB

Currently haven't tried any other method for this issue.

```
con.Open();

SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    tsLblStatus.Text = "Processing student.... " + " " + rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
    this.Refresh();

    var people_id = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
}

if ()
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EVENT_ID)
                        FROM [Table]
                        WHERE (PEOPLE_ID =@PEOPLE_ID ) AND (EVENT_ID LIKE 'MATH%')";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PEOPLE_ID", people_id);
```

So I'm trying to get it to use `people_id` (which is the ID that would be in the reader) as the parameter for the query but I'm unsure how to do so.

Comment: if both the DBs are same why don't you write a single query joining tables containing `people_id` and `[Table]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```cs
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EVENT_ID)
                        FROM [Table]
                        WHERE (PEOPLE_ID =@PEOPLE_ID ) AND (EVENT_ID LIKE 'MATH%')";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PEOPLE_ID", people_id));
```

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PEOPLE_ID",people_id); will add the
people_id in sql query at @PEOPLE_ID.